# convert List to array using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a list that I pulled from an API and convert it to a list.  The list does return other data but i have code in there to return just the data I want( it could be wrong)

```
//this pulls the data
public List<AccountBalance> CorpAccounts(int CORP_KEY, string CORP_API, int USER)
{
    List<AccountBalance> _CAccount = new List<AccountBalance>();
    EveApi api = new EveApi(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER);
    List<AccountBalance> caccount = api.GetCorporationAccountBalance();
    foreach (var line in caccount)
    {

        //everyting after
        string apiString = line.ToString();
        string[] tokens = apiString.Split(' ');
        _CAccount.Add(line);
    }
    return _CAccount;
}


//I am trying to convert the list to the array here
private void docorpaccounts()
{
    string[] corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER).ToArray();
}
```

With that code I get this error:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'EveAI.Live.AccountBalance[]'
>   to 'string[]'

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Error is self describing that you need `AccountBalance[]` instead of `string[]`.

Comment: I think to fix your problem you'd want to change `List<AccountBalance> _CAccount = new List<AccountBalance>();` to `List<string> _CAccount = new List<string>();`. And also `public List<AccountBalance> CorpAccounts()` to `public List<string> CorpAccounts`. That's one way you could fix your problem

Comment: The array type will have to match the list type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to assign `AccountBalance[]` into `string[]` - as error says.

Unless you really need `string[]` you should change variable declaration to `AccountBalance[]`:

```
private void docorpaccounts()
{
    AccountBalance[] corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER).ToArray();
}
```

Or specify how the `AccountBalance` should be transformed to be a `string`. e.g. using `ToString` method:

```
private void docorpaccounts()
{
    string[] corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER)
                           .Select(x => x.ToString())
                           .ToArray();
}
```

or one of its properties

```
private void docorpaccounts()
{
    string[] corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER)
                           .Select(x => x.MyStringProperty)
                           .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*`List<T>.ToArray` Method* ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx))

Syntax:

> public T[] ToArray()

So if you have `List<AccountBalance>` you should have `AccountBalance[]` when you invoke `ToArray` method.

Try this:

```
AccountBalance[] corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER).ToArray();
```

As @BenjaminGruenbaum mention in comment, the better option will be using var keyword ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)):

```
var corpbal = cwaa.CorpAccounts(CORP_KEY, CORP_API, USER).ToArray();
```

Comment: Or just use `var` and let type inference work it's magic and abstract thinking about this sort of thing from you.